# Also define the standard property 'grid-column' for compatibility

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm new to SASS and I'm trying to create a simple for loop in SASS for create grid classes. I have five boxes in my grid. Basically this is what I'm trying to do for each box:

```
.box1 {
    grid-area: box1;
    width: 100%;

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And this is my SASS code:

```
$gridBox: 5;

    @for $i from 1 through $gridBox {
        .box#{$i} {
            grid-area: box + $i;
            width: 100%;

            img {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
```

I checked main.css file and SASS automatically adds `-ms-grid-row` and `-ms-grid-column` to box classes. Because there is no `grid-row` and `grid-column` VS Code gives an error and wants me to also define standard properties but I'dont want to add them. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you just disable the rule?

Comment: I disabled and my problem solved. Thanks.